# VBA: How to assign find last row code to a function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to assign find last row code to a function (`Private Sub findLastRowFn`)
so that I can call it whenever I needed it. I have a running code but I can not assign it to a function.

Here is the code that I want to assign to a function

```
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCell As Range
' use Find function to get last row
Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
    LastRow = LastCell.Row
Else
    MsgBox "Error!", vbCritical
End If
```

And something like this is what I'm trying to achieved.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  findLastRowFn
    .Range("BK2:BQ" & LastRow).Select
      borderMeFn
      alignLeftItalicFn
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function:

```
Function findLastRowFn(ws As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCell As Range

    ' use Find function to get last row
    Set LastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        findLastRowFn = LastCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Error!", vbCritical
    End If

End Function
```

And in your `Sub`, use:

```
LastRow = findLastRowFn(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"))
```